# OS X equivalent to Win Ctrl+Shift+End

Tags: macos, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> in Windows Explorer to select a list of files in a folder.  I'm trying to figure out if there is a similar method in OS X, but no luck.

I know I can hold <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> and select a list, but that is file by file.

Answer (score 7):

I found it!

1. Select your file.
2. Hold down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Option</kbd> keys, then press the <kbd>down</kbd> (to select down) or <kbd>up</kbd> key.

Hopefully I'll remember that next time I'm dealing with it ...

Comment: Rollback to rev 1: the suggested edit broke the answer for Finder, which is what the user is asking about ("Win Explorer"). For lists in other applications, see the other answer by 175/Lri. cc @ChrisF

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd> should work in most text views.

In many other types of views like Finder's file views you can use <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who found this based on the title and is looking for "OS X equivalent to Win Ctrl+Shift+End" when selecting text from any point to the end in a WEB PAGE, here is the solution I found through trial and error:

First, select at least one character where you want to start selecting. Then press the following keyboard combination:

<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd>

I hope this helps others who are looking for this answer

Comment: Works only on Web page?

Answer (score 0):

I am having a little trouble understanding what exactly you are trying to do, but <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> will select them all

Comment: I don't think it's a "select all" thing, more like a "select from here to the end" thing. And I want the answer to that too! :)

Comment: Yes, what John Rudy said.